# Proper arguments as const or operands

Tags: c, struct, arguments, constants, operands

Do you feel it is important to strictly use `const` every time the value won't be changed or pass arguments as pointers only when the data will be modified?

I'd like to do things right but if a `struct` passed as an argument is large in size, don't you want to be passing the address instead of copying the data?  Usually it seems like just declaring the `struct` argument as an operand is most functional.

```
//line1 and line2 unchanged in intersect function
v3f intersect( const line_struct line1, const line_struct line2); 
//"right" method?  Would prefer this:
v3f intersect2( line_struct &line1, line_struct &line2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v3f intersect( const line_struct line1, const line_struct line2);
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
v3f intersect(line_struct line1, line_struct line2);
```

in terms of external behavior, as both hand copies of the lines to `intersect`, so the original lines cannot be modified by the function. Only when you *implement* (rather than declare) the function with the `const` form, there's a difference, but not in external behavior.

These forms are distinct from

```
v3f intersect(const line_struct *line1, const line_struct *line2);
```

which doesn't have to copy the lines because it passes just pointers. This is the preferred form in C, especially for large structures. It is also required for [opaque types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

```
v3f intersect2(line_struct &line1, line_struct &line2);
```

is not valid C.

Comment: The two first prototypes are not equivalent. In the second function you can modify your arguments in the function body.

Comment: Depending upon the compiler, applying const to pass-by-value parameters may aid optimization.  The compiler should interpret the const qualifier as a statement that no writes are permitted to the parameter.

Comment: @ouah: you're right, added that they're equivalent in external behavior.

Answer (score 0):

C has no reference (&).

In C, use a pointer to a `const` structure as your parameter type:

```
v3f intersect(const line_struct *line1, const line_struct *line2);
```

So only a pointer will be copied in the function call and not the whole structure.